# Chart.js: Disable Y-Axis, when graph is disabled via Legend

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, legend, axis

is it possible to hide the Y-Axis for a graph that has been disabled via the legend?
Right now it looks pretty messy, as disabled-graph-Y-Axis are just reset to the default range.
[Picture of the chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTdHw.png)

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you make your axes, instead of setting `display: true` set it to `display: 'auto'` this will make it so that when all datasets that are linked to that axis are hidden the axis disapears